# how to interpret gradient boost model & results in R?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I'm using R to model votes. I've found that the extreme gradient boost `xgbTree` algorithm gives nice results. I'm a newbie and don't really know how to interpret the model. My understanding is `xgbTree` is simply a gradient boost model, which runs fast.

If I use the caret package, I know there is a nice `varImp()` function that shows me the relative importance of features.

I can also compute the MSE to judge the prediction results.

Other than that, I don't have an idea how to interpret the model and judge predicted results. Was hoping someone could help me understand this in a general sense.

```
m1<-train(votes~.,data=trainset,method="xgbTree") 
p1<-predict(m1,newdata=testset)
```

I found the following information about the model in R, but not sure how to interpret it from a high-level perspective.

```
>summary(m1)
            Length Class              Mode       
handle          1  xgb.Booster.handle externalptr
raw         68304  -none-             raw        
xNames         11  -none-             character  
problemType     1  -none-             character  
tuneValue       3  data.frame         list       
obsLevels       1  -none-             logical 

> m1$bestTune
  nrounds max_depth eta
8     100         3 0.3

> print(m1)
eXtreme Gradient Boosting 

70001 samples
   11 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 
Summary of sample sizes: 70001, 70001, 70001, 70001, 70001, 70001, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  max_depth  nrounds  RMSE       Rsquared   RMSE SD      Rsquared SD
  1           50      1.0130456  0.7681330  0.010918047  0.007353824
  1          100      1.0038036  0.7723058  0.010863621  0.007558934
  1          150      0.9989381  0.7744915  0.010900582  0.007602353
  2           50      0.9851318  0.7806992  0.010356168  0.007234972
  2          100      0.9752206  0.7850671  0.010193392  0.007342830
  2          150      0.9711467  0.7868439  0.010170191  0.007324614
  3           50      0.9723670  0.7863109  0.010728093  0.007085609
  3          100      0.9676703  0.7883940  0.010288853  0.006705919
  3          150      0.9674846  0.7884925  0.009959612  0.006718457

Tuning parameter 'eta' was held constant at a value of 0.3
RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final values used for the model were nrounds = 150, max_depth = 3 and eta = 0.3.
```

What's the best way to analyze the prediction results besides MSE? Can we compute confidence intervals? etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ch.8 of "Introduction to Statistical Learning with R" not only discusses gradient boosting but has actual code on using gbm.

Comment: Thanks @aginensky, I think this is right link (correct me if not): http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/  in particular, page 331 relates to GBM. Was hoping there'd be more details.

Comment: That is the right link.  There is more than one page devoted to gbm.  I would actually read the discussion on bagging and probably rf too.  There is also implementation in the "R lab' section.  Have a look at this video (Tibshirani) for a nice explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPqtzj5VZus&list=PL0FVxN48mhgcin_Tv6zmwIIS6Fa5Sm9Tp .  Since it's about 35 min (as I recall) it should give you more information.

Comment: I'm loath to say, "Oh you want more details, just look at Elements of Statistical Learning", so I won't .  It will have a more mathematical approach with more details.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'm really new here so only looking for high-level information.